# How to add spelling suggestions to PHP/SQL search script

Tags: php, mysql, search

Creating a search function on my site using php/sql, simple enough - just using a SELECT ALL query on the database using the LIKE clause and echoing the result on the page. My question is, how can I add spelling suggestions in case the user mistyped their search query. Mysql doesn't return anything unless the search term matches exactly with the database content, e.g. "Dofs" will not return "Dogs". So how can spelling suggestions be added?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Following you will find an excellent article by Peter Norvig on how to write a spell checker:

http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html

and the following two links are implementations in PHP of the code found in the article:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4859.html
http://soundofemotion.com/spellcorrect.txt

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm the author of that class and I'm really happy to know that it's been useful to you guys! It works pretty well indeed, for small strings it's really nice and won't require you to install any external dependency or native library, but if you need to deal with big strings it can get quite slow. So in those cases I'd recommend using something like aspell.

Answer (score 2):

What about PHP's [pspell](https://www.php.net/pspell) extension?

```
<?php
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");

if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, "dofs")) {
    $suggestions = pspell_suggest($pspell_link, "dofs");

    foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) {
        echo "Possible spelling: $suggestion<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

This PHP extension requires that you have **aspell** libraries installed.

Comment: Note: Per comment on the above link, pspell is no longer supported in 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out something like the following:

http://phpir.com/spelling-correction

You will need a dictionary and the levenstien function basically.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to [Joe's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075798/how-to-add-spelling-suggestions-to-php-sql-search-script/2075806#2075806), you can make a soap call to provide alternate spellings (based on a search engine's language corpus)

Yahoo Spelling Suggestion: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/spellingSuggestion.html

Google spelling request: 
http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html#1_3

Comment: Google link now defunct

Answer (score 0):

Coming here in March 2020, then https://tigitz.github.io/php-spellchecker/ is worth looking at.

From the docs:

PHP-Spellchecker is a spellchecker abstraction library for PHP. By providing a unified interface for many different spellcheckers, you’re able to swap out spellcheckers without extensive rewrites.

Using PHP-Spellchecker can eliminate vendor-lock in, reduce technical debt, and improve the testability of your code.