# CodeIgniter search Box spelling suggistion Like as Google

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I have developed Codeigniter Search box in My Application but how to Implement spelling suggestions like entered  "APLE" we suggest Did you mean "APPLE".

Anyone, Please help to sort out this functionality .

Controller Logic:

```
function deals_search() {

        $search_string = $this->input->post('search_keyword');
        $query = $this->consumer_model->get_serching_deals($search_string);
        $data['searched_deals_count'] = count($query);
        if ($query) {

            foreach ($query as $row) {
                $row->id = urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($row->deal_id, 'deal_id'));
                $serched_deals[] = $row;
            }

        $data['searched_deals'] = $serched_deals;
    } else {
        $data['no_deals_msg'] = "did not match the key word";
    }
    $data['search_string'] = $search_string;
    $data['category'] = $this->consumer_model->category_menu();
    $this->load->view('side_menu', $data);    //1)side  menu
    $this->load->view('common/consumer_menu'); //2)consumer main menu
    $this->load->view('search_deals', $data);
}
```

Query/Model Logic:

```
public function get_serching_deals($search_string)
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
FROM deal ds, merchant m, deal_cat dc, category c, reservation_dates rd, deal_reservation dr
WHERE (
deal_title LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR deal_title LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR actual_value LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR deal_price LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR deal_location LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR deal_brief_desc LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR deal_fine_print LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.mrt_name LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.address1 LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.address2 LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.city LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.state LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.zipcode LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.telephone1 LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.telephone2 LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.telephone2 LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  m.description LIKE '%$search_string%'
OR  c.ctg_name LIKE '%$search_string%'
)
AND ds.mrt_id = m.mrt_id
AND ds.dls_id =2
AND dc.deal_id = ds.deal_id
AND c.ctg_id = dc.deal_ctg_id
AND rd.reserve_id = dr.reserve_id
AND dr.deal_id = ds.deal_id
AND rd.date = '2013-08-29'")->result();
        return $query;
    }
```

View/Presentation Logic:

```
            <?php
            foreach ($searched_deals as $deal_data) {
                ?> 
     <div class="imgborder_reg">
            <div class="image-box_reg">
                <div class="discountLabel"><div class="discountText"><?= $deal_data->discount ?>% Off</div> </div>
                <div class="image-container_reg">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/deal_images/<?= $deal_data->deal_image ?>" alt="Food">
```

Comment: [This look very familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18526888/1207346)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add spelling suggestions to PHP/SQL search script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075798/how-to-add-spelling-suggestions-to-php-sql-search-script)

Comment: You need to rething this. Searching Apple on all those fields will be horrific returning things such as addresses like "Dappled Drive".

Comment: You really think that those OR LIKE '%...%' statements won't slow down your database?